# http://security.debian.org/dists/cosmic/Release 404 Not Found [IP: 151.101.184.204 80]

Tags: apt, updates, 18.10

```
kingcanty@kingcanty-HP-Pavilion-17-Notebook-PC:~$ sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 ht tp://mirror.team-cymru. org/ubuntu cosmic InRelease
Ign:2 ht tp://security.debian. org cosmic InRelease                                                                                                                            
Err:3 ht tp://security.debian. org cosmic Release                                                                                                                              
  404  Not Found [IP: 151.101.184.204 80]
Hit:4 ht tp://mirror.team-cymru. org/ubuntu cosmic-updates InRelease                                                                                     
Hit:5 ht tp://mirror.team-cymru. org/ubuntu cosmic-backports InRelease                                                                                   
Hit:6 ht tp://mirror.team-cymru. org/ubuntu cosmic-security InRelease                                                              
Hit:7 ht tp://ppa.launchpad.net/danielrichter2007/grub-customizer/ubuntu cosmic InRelease                                         
Get:8 ht tp://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-security InRelease [88.7 kB]                           
Reading package lists... Done                                 
E: The repository 'ht tp://security.debian.org cosmic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
kingcanty@kingcanty-HP-Pavilion-17-Notebook-PC:~$
```

kubuntu 18.10

```
# deb cdrom:[Kubuntu 18.10 _Cosmic Cuttlefish_ - Release amd64 (20181017.2)]/ cosmic main multiverse restricted universe
# deb cdrom:[Kubuntu 18.10 _Cosmic Cuttlefish_ - Release amd64 (20181017.2)]/ cosmic main multiverse restricted universe
deb ht tp://mirror.team-cymru.org/ubuntu/ cosmic main restricted universe
deb ht tp://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ cosmic-security main restricted universe
deb ht tp://mirror.team-cymru.org/ubuntu/ cosmic-updates main restricted universe

deb ht tp://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-security main restricted

# See ht tp://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
#deb ht tp://mirror.team-cymru.org/ubuntu/ cosmic restricted
# deb-src ht tp://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ cosmic main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
#deb ht tp://mirror.team-cymru.org/ubuntu/ cosmic-updates restricted
# deb-src ht tp://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ cosmic-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
# deb-src ht tp://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ cosmic universe
# deb-src ht tp://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ cosmic-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb ht tp://mirror.team-cymru.org/ubuntu/ cosmic multiverse
# deb-src ht tp://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ cosmic multiverse
deb ht tp://mirror.team-cymru.org/ubuntu/ cosmic-updates multiverse
# deb-src ht tp://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ cosmic-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb ht tp://mirror.team-cymru.org/ubuntu/ cosmic-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src ht tp://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ cosmic-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb ht tp://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu cosmic partner
# deb-src ht tp://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu cosmic partner

# deb ht tp://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-security main restricted
# deb-src ht tp://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-security main restricted
# deb ht tp://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-security universe
# deb-src ht tp://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-security universe
deb ht tp://mirror.team-cymru.org/ubuntu/ cosmic-security multiverse
# deb-src ht tp://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-security multiverse
```

the 7th line was the problem, it was changed from 
    'deb ht tp://security.debian.org/ cosmic universe restricted main'

result
kingcanty@kingcanty-HP-Pavilion-17-Notebook-PC:~$ sudo apt-get update
[sudo] password for kingcanty: 
Hit:1 http://mirror.team-cymru.org/ubuntu cosmic InRelease
Hit:2 http://mirror.team-cymru.org/ubuntu cosmic-updates InRelease
Hit:3 http://mirror.team-cymru.org/ubuntu cosmic-backports InRelease
Hit:4 http://mirror.team-cymru.org/ubuntu cosmic-security InRelease
Hit:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/danielrichter2007/grub-customizer/ubuntu cosmic InRelease
Get:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-security InRelease [88.7 kB]
Fetched 88.7 kB in 2s (53.3 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
kingcanty@kingcanty-HP-Pavilion-17-Notebook-PC:~$

Comment: `cosmic` is Ubuntu version name, so Debian  apt servers should not have release files for Ubuntu version in the first place. Consider getting rid of that apt server in the config file and using security.ubuntu.com instead

Comment: thanks, could you explain how to do that? edit the /etc/apt/sources.list file?

Comment: Apt servers are typically specified in `/etc/apt/sources.list` or `/etc/sources.list.d` directory, with typically a file per repository in the former directory. So, open the `/etc/apt/sources.list` and replace `security.debian.org` with `security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu` The full line should look like `deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-security main restricted` (you can also add `universe` after main and restricted if you use any software from that type of repository). After that save the file and re-run `apt-get update`. If that works, I'll post a proper answer instead of a comment

Comment: Get:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-security InRelease [88.7 kB]
Fetched 88.7 kB in 2s (50.1 kB/s)                              
Reading package lists... Done
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list:7
W: Target Packages (main/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list:7
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list:7

Comment: OK, from the posted contents of the config file you have  `deb ht tp://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ cosmic-security main restricted universe
` in line 4. So line 7 is unnecessary. Remove line 7 and update again

Comment: i posted the output from apt-get update, what does the in release mean

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I fix a 404 Error when using a PPA or updating my package lists?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-when-using-a-ppa-or-updating-my-package-lists) Your [last update](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/1115978/5) looks like the correct output.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your APT sources.list contains a reference to security.debian.org, which is for Debian, not Ubuntu.  While their repository is compatible with APT, you won't find anything for your operating system there.  In particular, the error message indicates that they have no release called "cosmic".

The line that causes the problem appears to be:

```
http://security.debian.org cosmic Release
```

Comment: so remove 'cosmic' out of that line?

Comment: No, that's the only valid part of the line.  I think the line itself needs to be removed.  But I don't know if that would leave any lines missing.  Posting  your full sources.list might help.  Or explaining how the Debian line got there - it wouldn't have happened randomly.

Comment: source list is to large for comment area

Comment: i posted my sources.list  to the end of the question